# Splitting a xml file based on certain tags using VTD-XML or any other method

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, vtd-xml

Below is my xml file that I want to split. I need to split this xml file in such a way at each xml file will have one member information. Now can I do that using VTD-XML?

[The mail xml file to split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AInoH.png)

```
This files can have hundreds of Members (I just took two members to understand the problem). 
Now this file must split in multiple xml files in such a way that each xml file have only one member information. Also the output must be in the form of List<String> where all individual xml files will be stored in the form of string.(I need to return the output in List<String> form).
The individual xml file should have (NoOfMembers = 1) and (TotalSalary = salary of that particular member).
The splits of above xml should be like these two.
```

[first individual xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLFH1.png)

and

[second individual xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Xsu.png)